# Ubuntu does not receive third button mouse click

Tags: wireless, mouse

I am using a Lacerto bilingual wireless keyboard plus mouse. It works fine using left, right mouse and the wheel. However the click on the wheel and the click on the middle button do not work.

I tried out `xinput test <nr of mouse>`, the left and right button plus the scrolling of the wheel are reported. Click on the wheel and on the middle button are not noticed at all.On win platform everything works and does not need a particular driver. Any idea which driver I could use on Ubuntu?

Comment: Does it work like a middle-click, if you click left and write buttons at the same time (within a few milliseconds)? Do you know how to modify the settings of your mouse (check in the manual of the mouse)?

Comment: Clicking on the middle mouse button does not generate any event.
  xinput --test <device-number>
  generates events on left mouse click, right mouse click and scrolling of wheel. When I click the wheel nothing happens, nothing happens also when I click the little middle button near the wheel.

Comment: some software succeeds to emulate middle button clicks. e.g. blender emulates the middle mouse button with "alt" + left mouse button  
  pressing left and right button together does not deliver any result

Comment: Thanks for these details. Please answer also to the two questions in my first comment.

Comment: Does it work like a middle-click, if you click left and write buttons at the same time (within   few millisecond
s)?    NO, nothing happens, xinput does not receive any different:
 button press   3  
button press   1  
button release 1  
button release 3 
 Do you know how to modify the settings of your mouse (check in the manual of the mouse)?
 No idea, the mouse came without specs about this (lacerto)

Comment: There might be some special commands, that you can only guess, if there is no manual. It is also possible, that there is no linux driver for the lacerto hardware, and therefore there is not much we can do. Does it work corretly in Windows? In that case you can give it to someone who runs Windows and get a mouse that works in Linux. If you need a wireless mouse you had better search the internet for such a mouse or maybe ask at [the Ubuntu Forums in the forum for hardware](https://ubuntuforums.org/forumdisplay.php?f=332). (Standard wired mice will almost always work out of the box in Linux.)